# software adding annotation and comments for screenshot

Tags: software-rec, web-development, annotations

Is there a software that you can recommend that lets you doodle or add annotation in screenshot?

I need to be productive to my web-developer if I'm doing some instruction or comment on his websites. Example, I print-screen his website from internet Explorer and I neeed to add some comment, some arrows or highlights etc. So it would be much easier for me to give instruction or elaborate.

Is there a software you can recommend? I would go for Photoshop because It just make a simple job complicated. I need a software that is more catered in that job.

I'm running on Windows 7. I usually do print-screen on Chrome, Mozilla and Internet Explorer.

Comment: What OS do you want to do this on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Mac, either [LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) (My favorite), or [Skitch](http://skitch.com/).

For Windows, [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/default.asp) is great, or [Screenshot Captor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html).

For Linux, I like [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/).

Comment: Skitch is also available for Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac OS X, I'd suggest using [Skitch](http://skitch.com/). It does exactly what you describe, lets you take screenshots and annotate them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its windows, [paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/) - add a new layer, do whatever you need to, set layer transparency if needed, then save. It also has a nice simple way to do arrows.

Any basic drawing app could do what you need tho.