# Which screenshot annotation tool (if any) was used to create this attached screenshot?

Tags: macos, screenshot

*[Of course, I checked that it was not a tool cited in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/287196/software-adding-annotation-and-comments-for-screenshot) or any other superuser question prior to posting]*

Do you recognize the tool used to create this nice-looking annotated screenshot? Or do you think it's just a custom image (e.g. Photoshoped)?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshoped one, but somme good anotations tools are available on [here](http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=screenshot%20editor#hl=fr&sa=X&ei=8pkLT9ruE4Wy8QObw8GnBg&ved=0CCQQvwUoAA&q=screenshot%20annotation&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=8a2c3ba125d43da2&biw=1680&bih=882) !

But you can easily make a Photoshop Scripts for semi-auto screenshot edit ! =)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how do you it's Photoshop? Thanks!

Comment: We are never really sure, but I can say that's a Photoshoped one by simply looking at the rendering of fonts.. Absolutely not the same... On the annotation there is the photoshop serif... 
That's my opinion ! =)

Comment: Ok, you convinced me :)

Comment: You can make an jQuery scripts to annotes like thaht ! =)